# Understanding Python classes

Tags: python, class

I am trying to learn about python classes, but I don't understand something. Why does this simple example not return "6"? It returns `<function TEST.f at 0x00000000029ED378>` instead. I have also tried `TEST.f()` but then he tells me that the argument `self` is missing. Shouldn't `self` only exist inside the class and python fills it in automatically?

```
#! coding=utf-8

class TEST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 6
    def f(self):
        return(self.x)

print(TEST.f)
```

Comment: No, I changed it to "f" now, but the problem stays the same.

Comment: `print(TEST.f)` as such should work - it prints the textual representation of the unbound method `f`. A function or method call is always performed with `()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class.

```
test = TEST()
print test.x()
```

But you also need to call the method and the variable different things.

```
class TEST:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 6
    def x(self):
        return(self._x)
```

Otherwise you're redefining the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make your code work:

1. As aychedee said, create a TEST instance, and invoke method `f` from
   the instance:

   ```
   >>> TEST().f()
   6
   ```
2. Another way is to create a TEST instance t, and pass it the
   method `f`:

   ```
   >>> t = TEST()
   >>> TEST.f(t)
   6
   ```

   Remember the `self` argument of your method `f`?  Basically, this is to explicitly pass the TEST instance `t` to method `f`.

Comment: That said, the second one is just to show how it works. In real life, you would exclusively use the first one, possibly in the form `t = TEST()` `t.f()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance just as shown.

```
test = Test()
test.f()
```